# change DPI of image from 72 to 300 using intervention

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with `laravel` and using `in` for image processing.
I want to increase DPI of image. I didn't see any documentation regarding DPI  [here](http://image.intervention.io/). Is there any solution in `php` or any other method to do with `php` or `laravel`?

Comment: You can try this - http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intervention Image does not support this, but you can change DPI with imagemagick using [`-unit PixelsPerInch`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#units) option. For example:

```
exec('convert -units PixelsPerInch originalImage -resample 300 outputIamge');
```

Comment: can you explan how to implement step by step

Comment: That 's work fine  , you are awesome

Answer (score 4):

I just had to solve this problem and here is the solution I came up with. First, I had to install Imagick. The general process I used on my local mac running Apache, PHP 7.1, and Laravel was the following.

Using Terminal, install the Imagemagick ghostscript dependency

```
brew update
brew install ghostscript
```

Install ImageMagick

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Install Imagick php extension (pkg-config is only needed if you dont already have it. Terminal will let you know if it is missing).

```
brew install pkg-config
pecl install imagick
```

Activate the imagick php extension by adding the following line to the bottom of your php.ini file. I had to use phpinfo() to figure out where mine was located.

```
extension=imagick.so
```

For PHP 7.1 I had to also install the following. Otherwise, Imagick would run fine in terminal but Imagick would not be found in php.

```
brew install php71-imagick
```

Then restart apache

```
sudo brew services restart php71
```

Once that's done, you should be good to use Imagick. From there you can change the driver of Intervention to use Imagick instead of GD. [See Intervention Docs](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/configuration)

```
$manager = new ImageManager(array('driver' => 'imagick'));
```

or if you're in Laravel, you can just update config/image.php and change your driver.

```
'driver' => 'imagick'
```

Now with Intervention, you can do everything you need to to your image.

```
$image = Image::make( 'some/image.jpg' );
$image->resize( $width, $height, function ($constraint) {
     $constraint->aspectRatio();
 })->stream('jpg');
```

Finally, you can get the Imagick object from Intervention and change the dpi.

```
$finalImage = $image->getCore(); //get Imagick object
$finalImage->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$finalImage->setImageResolution(300,300);
```

**Edit**

I ran into a problem where if I was seeding my db with terminal and automating the creation of thumbnails, I was getting a `"ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation."` error. Turns out my browser is using php 7.1 and my terminal was 5.something. So I had to do the following:

Run this in terminal to locate the php.ini it's using.

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Activate the imagick extension in that file like you did before.

```
extension=imagick.so
```

That should do it. Another option is to make terminal use the same php version as your apache. If you'd like to do that, I would search around for directions...there's a bunch of them floating around.

Answer (score -1):

The answer was given in 2016, but I couldn't do this solution in a serverless architecture. I fixed the dpi value of the canvas I created with the gd library with the [imageresolution](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageresolution.php) function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).