# How to maintain the dpi (dots per inch) of an image in laravel 5.2 using intervention package?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dpi, intervention

I am using Laravel 5.2. I have almost done the resizing of an image that runs fine. But i am facing one problem When i upload an image of 300 dpi it reduces the dpi to 96 dpi. I don't know what i am doing wrong.I am using Intervention Package of laravel5.2. Here i have done so far:-

```
// Input::file('image') -> upload file having dpi of 300
$height = 6048; //upload image height
$width = 4032;  //upload image width
xxlheight = ($height*60)/100;
$xxlwidth = ($width*60)/100;
$xxlFileName = str_random(4)."xxl".str_random(4).".".$extension;
Image::make(Input::file('image'))->resize($xxlwidth,$xxlheight)->save(storage_path('app/images/secureRealImages/'.$xxlFileName));
$getxxlimage = Image::make(storage_path('app/images/secureRealImages/'.$xxlFileName));
```

PLease Help me what i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change DPI of image from 72 to 300 using intervention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529385/change-dpi-of-image-from-72-to-300-using-intervention)

Comment: yeah i have seen that but not proper answer

Comment: It is not possible to do with `Intervention Package`